# Move members between Umbraco instances

Tags: sql-server, content-management-system, automation, umbraco

Within our automated build environment we have a dev, test, uat and live Umbraco 4 site.  All changes are moved via source control and courier currently.  This works for everything except members - changes to Umbraco members are ignored by courier.

At this stage we are making changes to members manually on each environment which is far from ideal.  Is there any way to automate the process of moving changes to members in Umbraco?

I should clarify this is the structure of members, not the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script that exports your members to an Excel file, and then you can use the CMS Import package to import them in the new instance:

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/cmsimport

If you want to transfer content you might want to take a look at Courier 2.5. It doesn't seem to support transfer of member though:

http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question. I am looking to transfer the structure of members, not the content.  As I said earlier and you confirmed, Courier does not support this.